# How to Create Wordpress Child Plugins , Just like a child theme ?

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I need to changes in wordpress plugin's core files , but problem is that when it will update it will overwrite my changes. So in this case can we make a child plugins just like a child theme functionality ? So i can make change in core files .

Comment: First thing in any plugin if its provide a hooks then you can modify it in your theme's functiosn.php file. Otherwise need to do change directly in plugin which is not a good idea.

Comment: not all plugins supports this some plugins like woocommerce supports this in that case you just have to create a folder in your theme and paste the files in that folder you want to modify.

Answer (score 1):

There's no such thing as a child plugin. What you could try doing is making a duplicate of the plugin and changing the folder name and the info in the plugin's header (so that WP doesn't try and update it). Keep both installed but with the original deactivated (you can't have both active at the same time). Then, when the original plugin gets updated, you can use a file compare tool (eg, Linux's diff command) to see what has changed and what you need to update to bring your copy into line with the original.

Or, you could reach out to the plugin's developer and ask them if there's a way to change what you need to without editing the code. A lot of plugins allow things to be changed using filters or actions, so you never know!